# Mac pydev debugging setup error - socket closed

Tags: eclipse, macos, debugging, pydev

I am a Mac user and have pydev 10.2.0 installed on Eclipse. I am able to run my simple lines of code, but when I hit the debug option it comes up with the error pictured. I am wondering if it has anything to do with my path configurations. Also pictured is the module the error message is referencing.

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zE3Mr.jpg)
[Referenced code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8J8AP.jpg)

I have tried uninstalling pydev and reinstalling, but it did nothing.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not post images of code or errors. Text is preferred so that we can try to reproduce the problem without having to re-type everything and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.

Answer (score 1):

After iOS 17.0 released, I received "socket closed" error when debugging with Eclipse PyDev. The console message showed that XCode required my agreement.

I opened XCode and accepted the agreement. The error no longer occurred.